# BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource() complexity

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

What is the complexity of a call to `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(ResId)`? Does it keep a reference to recently converted images? [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) has nothing about this.

The thing is I have a lot of markers that I want to pin on `GoogleMap` and a few are different. Considering low-end devices, would the better approach be to call `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(ResId)` every time or to keep the reference to the `BitmapDescriptor` it returns?